# How to check does user is not active more than 1 minute

Tags: mysql

Hello I tried to update a row in table if somebody is offline more than 1 minute, and set LoggedIn then as 0, but my SQL query doesn't work, what I do wrong?

```
"UPDATE acc SET LoggedIn='0' WHERE LastTimeActive<(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `date_sub()`:

```
UPDATE acc
    SET LoggedIn = '0'
    WHERE LastTimeActive < date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE);
```

Comment: again, one little thing... Thank you!

Comment: @AbdulManaf I know, but I had to wait 15 minutes, same as all people do.

Comment: @user3251400 : Its your wish, But I don't understand your logic.

Comment: @AbdulManaf if(topicstarted < 15min){echo "you have to wait 15 minutes before you can vote}